# Faster SQL query on two table matching

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that I am trying to perform matching on with the following query:

```
select * from task1,task2
where task1.From_Number=task2.To_Number
and task1.Start_Time<task2.Start_Time;
```

It will work eventually but is taking forever.  The tables have 33 columns and one has around 45k rows and the other 500k rows.  There are duplicates in various columns and no column is unique so there isn't a primary key.  The tables were imported from spreadsheets.

There are a bunch of phone call logs and as mentioned, there are several duplicates in each column.  What can I do to get this query to run faster?  I am only matching against a few columns but need to print all columns and output the result into a csv.

Comment: why select *? whats the explain plan like?

Comment: Do you have indexes? I would bet an index on task1(from number, start_time) and another on task2(to_number, start_time) would make things work better.

Comment: What are the Clustered and Non-Clustered Indexes on this?  As you mentioned From_Number and To_Number is not Unique so Worst Case you could get 45k X 500k Rows back.  But you still need an Index on at least From_Number and To_Number so that it doesn't do a Loop and Table Scan.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I hadn't really used indexes before so I will read more on them and this helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do is create an non-unique index on both columns in both tables.

Read the [MySQL documentation on creating an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

Something like:

```
create index task1_idx
on     task1
( From_Number
, Start_Time
)
```

And:

```
create index task2_idx
on     task2
( To_Number
, Start_Time
)
```

Comment: Perfect.  What had sat for 15 minutes now only took 2.6 seconds.  Thanks!  I will accept this answer when I get home.